# Problem with messages if unanswered of out of business hours

Tags: twilio

Edit: resolved. Another question - how to play mp3 message in case of no answer after 30 sec?

*I stucked with twilio settings.
We need to play mp3 message (because our language is not supported by twilio).
This is actual function (I followed manual from blog https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/06/custom-javascript-twilio-functions-code-studio-flows.html)*

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    // With timezone:
    // In Functions/Configure, add NPM name: moment-timezone, version: 0.5.14
    // Timezone function reference: https://momentjs.com/timezone/
    let moment = require('moment-timezone');
    //
    // timezone needed for Daylight Saving Time adjustment
    let timezone = event.timezone || 'Europe/Vienna';
    console.log("+ timezone: " + timezone);
    //
    const hour = moment().tz(timezone).format('H');
    const dayOfWeek = moment().tz(timezone).format('d');
    if ((hour >= 9 && hour < 17) && dayOfWeek <= 7) {
        // "open" from 9am to 5pm, PST.
        response = "open";
    } else {
        response = "after";
    }
    theResponse = response + " : " + hour + " " + dayOfWeek;
    console.log("+ Time request: " + theResponse);
    callback(null, theResponse);
};
```

I functions configuration, I set moment-timezone version 0.5.26 (but also tried 0.5.14), and twilio 3.37.1 (also older version = no sucess)

And this is studio flow used:

[image]

I also tried this flow, but no success:

[image]

If I calling to our twilio number out of business hours, it does not play out of business message, but it play message before call and then connect to out twilio number.

Thank you for advice and help (dummy here)

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. 
Box "Access control" was checked, that's why this flow does not worked.
After unchecking, it works.

Another question here - how I can play mp3 message in case of no answer after 30sec? Thank you

image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d2x9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Set your Connect Call To widget timeout to 30 seconds and check the [DialStatus](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#dialcallstatus) of this Connect Call To widget using the follow-up Split Based On widget, to see if the value was other than completed and if so, play .mp3 using the Say/Play widget. Watch out for the far-end having voice mail enabled, which may pickup before 30 seconds.